# API post body is null after migrating from .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET5

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I migrated a Web API from .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET5 and also upgraded Entity Framework 6 to Entity Framework Core 5. I am having some issues which I am resolving overall but one of them which I cannot seem to solve is that wherever I have [FromBody] someBodyVar it is being set to null wherever the client side is sending a GUID as an empty string or as null but the model on Web API is a non nullable GUID. This is generally happening when there is a model and has an ID (of type GUID) but the client side sets it to null or empty string when the request is a new one. I know that this is not ideal but is there a way how I can override the behaviour in order to get this to work? .NET Framework used to set such values to empty GUIDs automatically. I really need to get the same behaviour as I cannot change the front end.

The following is an example of a model:

```
[DataContract]
public class Entity
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "groupId")]
    public Guid? GroupId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "userId")]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

The following is the controller signature:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("add/{sessionId}")]
    public IActionResult AddEntity([FromRoute] Guid sessionId, [FromBody] Entity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            // entity is null here
            // do logic
            return Ok(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
```

The following is the service registration in Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>(); 
        });

        services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This fixes when we return a pure string instead of json
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        });

        // This is to use newtonsoft by default
        services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    }
```

From an Angular application, the ID can be set to an empty string ("") since in angular its ultimately a string and not a GUID so it can be set to "". When this is the case, entity is null in the controller, but when the front end sets it to an actual GUID, then entity is set correctly.

The following is the payload as sent from the Angular application:

```
 {
    id: "",
    userId: '211a924c-1f5f-4a3e-8cec-6ff3b89c67ac'
 }
```

Also, I have some controllers which uses the following due to image uploads:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(HttpContext.Request.Form["entity"]);
```

The above is still working properly with .NET5 but again, I do not want to change all the functionality to use the above as I would like to minimise my code changes as much as possible. What I would like is to change the configuration only. With the above, both the backend AND the frontend would need to change.

As already stated, the above was working 'correctly' in .NET Framework 4.6.

I tried removing the [FromBody] but the behaviour was still the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[FromBody] someBodyVar` isn't valid. Please add a [mre] rather than a wall of text. The difference you are seeing though is likely because of `System.Text.Json`, and you may need use `Newtonsoft.Json` instead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: can you add the data you are sending from angular?

Comment: @ChizT Angular model added

Answer (score 0):

We ended up having to change the frontend to not initialise the ID instead of initialising it to an empty string.